# Powershell - stuck at trying to parse some text

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to parse the text "Assassin's Creed® Odyssey" on this page: https://serialstation.com/trophies/NPWR/13822

I think I'm OK with this code:

```
$webRequest = Invoke-WebRequest "https://serialstation.com/trophies/NPWR/13822"
$webRequest.ParsedHtml.getElementById("filter-data-wrapper") | Select-Object innerText
```

But the returned result is:

```
innerText  
---------  
Loading...
```

I understand it's because of the loading applet or something, but I don't know how to do to pass it, can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance